DIY memmove(). (Asking for a friend, kinda...)
A few days ago, this answer was posted to a 2y.o. Stack Overflow question (public domain).
(The question about a presumed requirement of an intermediate buffer to implement memmove() can be found there, too.)
The original version of the answer contained two bugs that were quickly corrected.
Perhaps the code review comments I contributed to that answer were an incomplete assessment of that code, and may have been irrelevant in the context of a Stack Overflow Q&A.
Below is an exact copy/paste of the current suggested "roll-your-own" version of memmove().
void *memmove(void *target, const void *source, size_t length)
{
    {
        const unsigned char *cursor = source;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(cursor == target) {
                goto overlap;
            } else cursor++;
        }
    }
    // Here, we know there is not enough overlap for a simple loop to fail
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        i[(unsigned char *)target] = i[(unsigned char *)source];
    }
    return target;
    
    // This case handles the overlapping situation, where we run the loop backward.
    overlap:
    for(size_t i = length; i-- > 0;) {
        i[(unsigned char *)target] = i[(unsigned char *)source];
    }
    return target;
}

Acknowledging my own limitations and personal preferences in "code evaluation", here I am hoping for assessments by anyone from interested SMEs to "armchair quarterback" readers. Thank you.
Please limit all answers to evaluations of this isolated code snippet, disregarding any other meta-considerations.

@Harith When I use or recommend this code to another, I, or "my friend", take on the title of "maintainer"... Asking for an assessment here does not seem out-of-place.

For the record, I've just now been made aware of this "community's" rules and guidelines (that I had not discovered for myself.) I apologise for this transgression, and understand and accept the "closing" of this question. I am sorry.

license

posted to a 2y.o. Stack Overflow question (public domain).

Weellll, the fine print at the very bottom of that page explains

user contributions licensed under CC BY-SA

Whoops,

any other meta-considerations.

blew it already!
arithmetic
This seems expensive:
        const unsigned char *cursor = source;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (cursor == target) {
                goto overlap;
            } else cursor++;
        }

Wouldn't we rather ask whether
source <= target && target < source + length ?
And then do a pointer subtraction before we goto ?
(I am assuming that sometimes length is "big".)
Oh, wait, we don't even need to compute cursor, it's just a temp.
inversion
Yeah, you're going to need to write at least one comment for this.
        i[(unsigned char *)target] = i[(unsigned char *)source];

I get it, addition is commutative, and so is pointer addition.
But why?
If you put this into a codebase where colleagues may need
to read or maintain this line of code,
you need to at least offer a hint.
As written, this should not be merged from feature branch to main.
backwards
The pair of "copy a character" loops are nice, and simple.
So simple that I'm willing to believe -O3 could maybe
unroll, copy at least 64 (aligned) bits at a time, and
finesse the small leftover amounts at front and back.
It's worth benching your favorite target hardware to
measure whether the memory subsystem performs faster
on sequential forward scans than on backward scans.
If there's a discrepancy, you might want to complexify
the overlap case, so we make forward copies in two phases.
And then there would be two cases to consider,
according to whether source < target.
special case
If source == target it's a no-op and we can return at once.
Dunno how often that comes up,
outside of benchmark competitions.

Thank you. Re: "arithmetic". The relevant paragraph of the C spec states something like: "relative pointer comparison is ONLY valid when both pointers access the same array (or one element after)". The only permitted comparison for two pointers that, as in this case, are known to point toward two unrelated arrays is to test for ==. Using <, or <= for source and target is the old bug-bear, UB... Cheers! :-) (I'll cheerfully remove this comment if/when it becomes inapplicable to this answer.)

Cool. Sounds like it's leftover from processors that relied on segment + offset, where {source, target} could be reached via different segment registers. Sooo, the source code definitely warrants a /* comment */ to that effect, to help out the Gentle Reader. And, if we insist on "modern" compiler and/or hardware, surely we can find some combination where a sane comparison can be safely made, no? Or are we expecting -O3 to save us, and the optimizer will make the operation cheap when length is "big"?

"a sane comparison can be safely made" Only when the Spec Writers decide to make that an official part of the spec, and compliant compilers are revised... Yes, I believe the old 8086 memory addressing scheme with "segments" is one example of hardware than requires this less-than-sane "not defined" 'hic-cup'... Cheers! :-) (It might work on some implementations for some target hardware, but it's not because relative comparison is defined to always work by the spec.)

Re: "special case"... One of the tacit agreements about code posted to SO is "caveat emptor". Testing for this 'special case', or checking for NULL pointers is both implied and presumed by all readers... Good that you mention it, but in the context, it seems something to allow by the agreement of the rules of the game. Cheers! :-)

Well, I just meant for speed, not correctness. The OP code is fine, it leaves memory unchanged. It just maybe takes longer to do it than the system memmove(), and that’s always the benchmark target we’re worried about.

Just for the fun of it... I've used memmove() a few times, over the years. Each time was merely to open-up/shut-up a gap in an array. Oddly, each time, the caller "knew" (or could easily have known) which way the data was to be shifted. Each time, the caller could have used its "knowledge" to invoke a function to copy L-R or its companion function for R-L as required. Instead, set-up for memmove() was an opportunity for an "off by one" error/bug... Kinda wonder if "general purpose" memmove() was a bad idea. (Coders don't use strchr() when they know they want strrchr()... Hmm...)

The A20 line is amazing. And so would be a duet between Céline Dion and Raymond Chen about a wayward object: "Near, far, wherever you are..." // I understand that an 8086 doing a 20-bit pointer equality check will need to execute a few instructions for that. What I still don't grok is why it's OK to generate those instructions for ==, but back in the day a compiler would refuse to generate similar instructions for <.

My question has been closed (appropriately!) Mea culpa... Just to mention this for your consideration: Re: "copy 64 bits at a time"... In many instances, memmove() may be copying bytes such that either the source OR the destination does not conveniently align with an 8-byte buffer load. Eg source is at 24, but destination is at 57 (for the sake of illustration.) One-or-the-other pointers will not work with big chunks of bytes... Yours is a nice idea, and could work in some cases, but requires finicky logic to detect when it works and when it wouldn't. Just a point to ponder... Cheers!

Oh, sure. We mask off low order bits to find the “bulk middle”. And then there’s more than one way to finesse the leftover beginning and end. Such as Duff’s device.
